# Cannot Add React-Native to existing app

Tags: android, react-native

I have trouble adding react-native support to existing app. I'd like to enhance my android app with react-native support. In order to show my problem I've created "Hello World" android application from Android studio wizard, and now I'd like to add react-native to it. I am following react tutorials

- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html

But after adding react and installing app on device I am getting following error:

```
04-28 21:47:50.394 12537-12588/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_js
                                               Process: pl.fzymek.reactairquality, PID: 12537
                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: com.facebook.react.devsupport.JSException: Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly
                                                   at com.facebook.react.bridge.DefaultNativeModuleCallExceptionHandler.handleException(DefaultNativeModuleCallExceptionHandler.java:24)
                                                   at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSupportManagerImpl.handleException(DevSupportManagerImpl.java:246)
                                                   at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.onNativeException(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:465)
                                                   at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.access$400(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:51)
                                                   at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.CatalystInstanceImpl$NativeExceptionHandler.handleException(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:481)
                                                   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:33)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:196)
                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
                                                Caused by: com.facebook.react.devsupport.JSException: Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly
                                                   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:196) 
                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
                                                Caused by: com.facebook.jni.CppException: Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly
                                                   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:196) 
                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

My directory structure is as follow:

```
├── ReactAirQuality
│   ├── ReactAirQuality.iml
│   ├── app
│   ├── build
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── buildsystem
│   ├── gradle
│   ├── gradle.properties
│   ├── gradlew
│   ├── gradlew.bat
│   ├── index.android.js
│   ├── local.properties
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package.json
│   └── settings.gradle
```

Root dir (ReactAirQuality) is android app generated from Android studio wizard and inside this dir I am running `npm install` or `react-native start` commands.

Now, when I run `./gradlew clean installDebug` application is intalled on my device, but crashes when activity using react components is launched.

Application is hosted on github: https://github.com/fzymek/ReactAirQuality/tree/feature/react-native-support .

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might try starting from the other side...making a react native app and then merging your existing project into it

Comment: I've never added react-native to an existing app, always started them from scratch - but have you entered your ip address in the dev settings? The 'BatchedBridge' errors might have to do with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What seems to be wrong is that you are keeping all the files in the same directory which is not a way in react native.... so what you can do is :

1) create a fresh react native project and copy all the js files which are already prepared by you..

2) prepare package.json as per your requirement and link index.android.js and index.ios.js with your exsisting js files.

3) Now run `npm install`. If there is a pod file in ios folder then run `pod install`.

4) Last but not the least run `rnpm link` to link native modules..

The above code shows you the way how you can merge existing project with the new project..

The error in your code would have appeared due to the fact that you did not changed the settings to run the application in your device.

1) open dev menu `(command + m)`

2) select dev settings and in that put your ip address (@@@.@@@.@.@@:8081)

Cheers :)